# How to build .Net core application in Docker?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, docker-container

I am working on .Net core application. I am trying to build application using docker container. Below is my file structure.

Root Folder

```
-MerchWebServices
  -MerchWebServices.sln
  -Dockerfile
  -MWS.AspNetCoreApis
    -bin
    -obj
    -out
    -MWS.AspNetCoreApis
```

Below is my dockerfile

```
#FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY MWS.AspNetCoreApis/out .

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:44332
EXPOSE 44332

COPY scripts/entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/entrypoint.sh
CMD tail -f /dev/null
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MWS.AspNetCoreApis.dll"]
```

Using below command I am building my application.

```
docker build -t merchwebservices .
```

After running above command, image gets created successfully. After that I am running below command.

```
docker run -p 44332:44332 -d  merchwebservices
```

I am able to run this command. My container is running now. I am not able to run the web application on

> https://localhost:44332/swagger/index.html

I am not sure why I am not able to run the application now. Can someone help me to fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: how do you know the container is running and please define `I am not able to run the web application on...`. do you see any error in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you container is running by inspecting `docker ps` output.

Then try to access `http://localhost:44332/swagger/index.html`.

If your app doesn't require any certificate, no need to use `https`

If it doesn't work inspect `docker logs -f container_id` output

Comment: Hi Rok. My application doesnt requires any certification. I tried using http also. I went inside the container using docker exec. I can see all the required files there

Comment: what error do you see in the browser? can you access `http://localhost:44332` only?